# Where can I find dependencies to add to Sails.js application like Vue.js, Vuetify, and lodash?

Tags: sails.js

I'm looking for a place to find available dependencies that can be added to a Sails.js application in the assets/dependencies folder. I'm asking because I see that in this project https://github.com/mikermcneil/ration/tree/master/assets/dependencies they have dependencies for these things but I can't seem to find a repository or something similar for dependencies such as these online.

Answer (score 0):

Found it:
https://www.jsdelivr.com/

This place has all the .js files that I was looking for, as well as .css files